# Generate Graph with node and edge attributes from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx, network-analysis

I do have a pandas dataframe, that i want to convert into a network, with a structure like this:

[NodeID, TargetID, NodeAttr1, NodeAttr2]

But the catch is, that i do have some rows, in which the TargetID might be None, as there are Nodes that are not connected in the Network. 
Is there an easy way, to create a network structure and assign my attributes?

I have tried:

```py
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df)
```

But this method only gives me the option to add edge attributes, none to the nodes. Also it will create edges from my nodes that are not connected into the void. So not what i want.

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

d = {'NodeID': [1, 2], 'TargetID': [2, None], 'NodeAttr1': ['aaaa', 'bbbbb'], 'NodeAttr2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

node_df = df[df['Node_ID']]
edge_df = df[df.TargetID.notnull()]

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edge_df, 'NodeID', 'TargetID')
G.add_nodes_from(node_df['NodeID'])
```

This code will create the network i in an easy way, but i still have the problem, that I have trouble assigning attributes to my nodes.

Is there a solution to this problem, that is somewhat resource efficient, as i am creating lots of big graph structures.

Comment: i don't know if it's resource-efficient, but I think if you use the `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` function with the right arguments (i think you want to use `orient="index"`) to pass into `add_nodes_from`, you can probably get close. you may need to create two separate Graphs and compose them to merge the edges into the nodes with the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for  [`nx.set_node_attributes()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html). This function will allow you to create the needed attributes on your nodes from an already created network.

Example from the NetworkX function page:

```
G = nx.path_graph(3)
attrs = {0: {'attr1': 20, 'attr2': 'nothing'}, 1: {'attr2': 3}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)
```